# Department ID authentication on Canon iR-ADV 6575

Tags: drivers, printing, authentication, canon

My university just added a new printer - a Canon iR-ADV 6575. I was able to install the Canon iR-ADV 6575 UFR II ver.3.2 driver, but printing is not working. When I send a job, it says "Processing - Unable to get printer status."

I believe that the printer is supposed to require Department ID authentication, but it never asks me to authenticate. I've tried messing with the authentication settings, but haven't been able to get an authentication dialog to appear or been able to find where I could enter in credentials.

Comment: How are you trying to print? From which application? Can you provide more details?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Is this a printer you administer, or are you student (or faculty member) trying to connect to a printer that has been provided to you?

Comment: Check to see if your department _enabled_ ask for _authentication_ when they added the printer. That might be the issue.

Comment: So sorry to be AWOL. I've been swamped and haven't had time to try to work on this (I shouldn't have started a bounty right now!).

@luchonacho - Even trying to print a test page from the printers dialog doesn't work. I also tried printing from evince, I believe. Adrien - I am a student trying to connect to a printer.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly try resetting the printer to factory settings, and then see if the authentication does come up. Yes, the printer should require Department ID, I have no idea as to why the printer is not working.

EDIT: reading up more about this printer, here is what you are supposed

To enable Department ID Management with the DepartmentID Authenticaion, you need to register the Department ID and PIN.

1. Press   Management Settings > User Management > Department ID Management.
2. Press On.
   If you want to manage only with the System Manager ID and PIN without implementing Department ID Management, press Off.
   IMPORTANT:
   If you want to return the login service to the User Authentication and use the Department IDs, set Department ID Management to  and start the User Authentication. Assign Department IDs to users and set Department ID Management of the User Authentication to .
3. Press Register PIN  > Register.
4. Enter Department ID and PIN and press OK.
   Enter the same PIN again for confirmation, and press OK.
5. Press OK > OK.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe Jeremy is trying to connect to a printer set up by the university. He most likely cannot try resetting the printer to factory settings, or register a Department ID PIN (whatever that is). If I understand correctly, he is trying to send a PIN to the printer so that it accepts his printing job.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found some instructions that work - basically, you need to use the cque utility that Canon provides - http://pitak.net/blog/2014/11/20/canon-printer-department-id-job-accounting/